# Is it possible to Paginate a table using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination

Consider my table with ten rows and I want to show first three rows in page1 and so on... How to paginate a table using jquery? Any good plugin....

Comment: Yes it is. There's a good tutorial here: www.youtube.com/phpapplied

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are plugins to do this:

- https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/pagination/
- <s>http://beckelman.net/demos/jqueryTableSorterConPaging/default.aspx</s>

Also, there is a good tutorial here which covers all kinds of table manipulation in jQuery including pagination:  http://www.packtpub.com/article/jquery-table-manipulation-part1

Comment: Unfortunately, the first two links have been moved.

Comment: The jTable plugin is here: http://plugins.jquery.com/jTable/ with more information including links to documentation here: http://jtable.org/Home/Downloads.

Answer (score 12):

I prefer this one [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/).

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [Tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/) plugin, with its accompanying [pagination plugin](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/).

Answer (score 8):

```
<table class="paginated">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">A</th>
            <th scope="col">B</th>  
            <th scope="col">C</th> 
            <th scope="col">D</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>        
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>        
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>        
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>                
    </tbody>
</table>
```

-

```
<script>
$('td', 'table').each(function(i) {
    $(this).text(i+1);
});



$('table.paginated').each(function() {
    var currentPage = 0;
    var numPerPage = 10;
    var $table = $(this);
    $table.bind('repaginate', function() {
        $table.find('tbody tr').hide().slice(currentPage * numPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
    });
    $table.trigger('repaginate');
    var numRows = $table.find('tbody tr').length;
    var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);
    var $pager = $('<div class="pager"></div>');
    for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
        $('<span class="page-number"></span>').text(page + 1).bind('click', {
            newPage: page
        }, function(event) {
            currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
            $table.trigger('repaginate');
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }).appendTo($pager).addClass('clickable');
    }
    $pager.insertBefore($table).find('span.page-number:first').addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

-

```
<style>
table {
    width: 40em;
    margin: 2em auto;
}

thead {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

td {
    width: 10em;
    padding: 0.3em;
}

tbody {
    background: #ccc;
}

div.pager {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1em 0;
}

div.pager span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.8em;
    height: 1.8em;
    line-height: 1.8;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}

div.pager span.active {
    background: #c00;
}

</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LiquidSky/djav37tg/

Comment: lovely jquery code, thank you @Abdo-Host

Comment: why we need add css class `clickable` ? > .appendTo($pager).addClass('clickable')

Answer (score 5):

I think easiest is [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/). Link: http://www.datatables.net/ using "paging: true"

So code would be something like:

```
        $('#your-table').dataTable({
            "scrollY": "350px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "bSort": false,
            "paging": true
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

There's also [Pajinate](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Pajinate).

You can also just go to [the plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/) section of jQuery site and search keywords you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes.

There is a plugin for [jquery pagination](https://github.com/gbirke/jquery_pagination).

Comment: The new home of the source code is https://github.com/gbirke/jquery_pagination
The demo page is no longer functional - too many pages were linking to js file from the demo code instead of their own copy :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datatable` plugin.It is very useful with search and custom page number feature.

Comment: That helped but do add links as well. :) +1