# Paginate jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, html, datatable, pagination

I'm trying to paginate a table, but I can't do it. I post the last code I try.

```
function configureCountersTable(){
    $('#medicalListTable').DataTable({
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "language": {
            "info": "",
            "search": "Buscar:",
            "zeroRecords": "No hay datos para mostrar",
            "infoFiltered": "",
            "infoEmpty": ""
        }
    });

}
```

I have more than 400.000 rows, and I want to show only the first 20, with a paginate system.

I try this two answers on stackoverflow but it doesn't work for me. Any idea?

[jQuery Datatables pagination setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422797/jquery-datatables-pagination-setting/20423119)

[Is it possible to Paginate a table using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974246/is-it-possible-to-paginate-a-table-using-jquery)

Comment: 400,000 rows is far too much data to dump to the client side and expect HTML/JS to handle. You need to implement paging on the server side and pass each page to the data table. See [this](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side) for more information

Comment: you must use serverside processing, and load data using ajax

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that when I receive the data, some columns are null, and if they are null I don't add the column, so table format was incorrect. Now I can paginate.